# Ошибка C2679 бинарный "<<": не найден

Tags: c++

Изучаю C++ по книге, и при написании такого кода

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

char askYesNo1();
char askYesNo2(string question);

int main()
{
    char answer1 = askYesNo1();
    cout << "Thanks for answering: " << answer1 << "\n\n";
    char answer2 = askYesNo2("Do you wish to save your game?");
    cout << "Thans for answering: " << answer2 << "\n";

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

char askYesNo1()
{
    char response1;
    do
    {
        cout << "Please enter 'y' or 'n': ";
        cin >> response1;
    } while(response1 != 'y' && response1 != 'n');
    return response1;
}

char askYesNo2(string question)
{
    char response2;
    do
    {
        cout << question << " (y/n): ";
        cin >> response2;
    } while(response2 != 'y' && response2 != 'n');
    return response2;
}
```

Возникает ошибка "Ошибка C2679 бинарный "<<": не найден оператор, принимающий правый операнд типа "std::string" (или приемлемое преобразование отсутствует)" в этой функции:

```
char askYesNo2(string question)
    {
        char response2;
        do
        {
            cout << question << " (y/n): ";
            cin >> response2;
        } while(response2 != 'y' && response2 != 'n');
        return response2;
    }
```

Код пишу в Visual Studio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот эта строка:

```
cout << question << " (y/n): ";
```

Выводит объект типа `std::string`, который определён в заголовке `<string>`, там же определён соответствующий оператор вывода (operator<<), поэтому нужно подключить этот заголовок:

```
#include <string>
```

Иначе компилятор не знает, где ему взять этот оператор, о чём сообщение об ошибке и говорит.